# get column list using sed/awk/perl

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I have different files like below format

**Scenario 1 :**

```
File1
no,name
1,aaa
20,bbb

File2
no,name,address
5,aaa,ghi
7,ccc,mn
```

I would like to get column list which is having more number of columns and if it is in the same order

```
**Expected output for scenario 1 :**
no,name,address
```

**Scenario 2 :**

```
File1
no,name
1,aaa
20,bbb

File2
no,age,name,address
5,2,aaa,ghi
7,3,ccc,mn
```

Expected Results :

```
Both file headers and positions are different as a message
```

I am interested in any short solution using bash / perl / sed / awk.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -lne 'push @lines, $_;
           close ARGV;
           next if @lines < 2;
           @lines = sort { length $a <=> length $b } @lines;
           if (0 == index "$lines[1],", $lines[0]) {
               print $lines[1];
           } else {
               print "Both file headers and positions are different";
           }' -- File1 File2
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line and runs the code for each line
- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to printed lines
- [closing](http://p3rl.org/close) the special file handle [ARGV](http://p3rl.org/perlvar#ARGV) makes Perl open the next file and read from it instead of processing the rest of the currently opened file.
- [next](http://p3rl.org/next) makes Perl go back to the beginning of the code, it can continue once more than one input line has been read.
- [sort](http://p3rl.org/sort) sorts the lines by length so that we know the longer one is in the second element of the array.
- [index](http://p3rl.org/index) is used to check whether the shorter header is a prefix of the longer one (including the comma after the first header, so e.g. `no,names` is correctly rejected)